# Rspec Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

```
let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      "first_name" => "MyString",
      "last_name" => "LastName",
      "email" => "email@example.com",
      "password" => "password12345",
      "password_confirmation" => "password12345"
    }
  }

it "sets session when" do
        post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(valid_attributes.id)
end
```

when i run above test , it fails 
Failure/Error: expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(valid_attributes["id"])

expected: nil
 got: 1

But when i change it to below code , it passes the test. But what is the difference between these two. Why first one is failing.

```
it "sets session when" do
        post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(User.find_by(email: valid_attributes["email"]).id)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valid_attributes.id` has nothing to do with any Rails magic. You have assigned the value (hash) to `valid_attributes` in `let` and compare against it. This value was not changed during test execution, nor was updated from the database. `valid_attributes.id` was never set ⇒ it is `nil`.

In the latter case you perform a post action and then check that the value was successfully stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

`valid_attributes` is a simply a hash and it doesn't have anything to do with your `User` object. Your post will create a `User` object which will have an `id` which you are basically trying to check that exists via your test expectations.